# Why this is required for extension methods of super classes?

Tags: c#

Here is a sample code showing the oddity: (code fixed based on comment)

```
public class C{}
public static class E {
  public static void Foo(this C o) { }
 }
class D:C {
  void test() {
//  Foo(); // will not compile
    this.Foo(); // compile ok
  }
}
```

**naturally in a real scenario class C would be a class i do not have access to its source code**

Anyone knows why this odd requirement to use the this keyword?

Comment: I'm assuming that you intended for `D` to inherit from `C`. In your code sample, it doesn't.

Comment: and that foo() and this.foo() should be Foo() and this.Foo();

Comment: Neither of your snippets would compile, so either fix snippets or fix comments.

Comment: your compiler is broken, it does cascade inheritance!!!

Comment: Thanks for the comments - i fixed the code to mean what i wanted it to mean

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looking at the C# spec, section 7.6.5.2 specifies that extension method invocations only apply for method calls of the following formats:

> ```
> expr . identifier ( )  
> expr . identifier ( args )  
> expr . identifier < typeargs > ( )  
> expr . identifier < typeargs > ( args )
> ```

When it is a standalone method call, there is no `expr`, so it does not look for an extension method. This follows because without an `expr`, it doesn't know what the first argument of the extension method should be.

Comment: +1 for the link to the spec, though I disagree that it doesn't know what the first argument should be. It will always be "this", as any unqualified function call on an instance method is 100% identical if called as `this.Foo()`, so there's no reason that it can't infer the `this.`. In line with Eric Lippert's "magic words" objection, this seems like just an oversight (or attempt to limit possible confusion), as the compiler *can* know with 100% certainty what the first argument should be.

Comment: I suspect it's due to the same syntax being able to call static methods on the containing class - for one, there's a `this`, and for the other, there isn't, but both look the same. Having a preceding `expr` limits it to instance methods.

Answer (score 2):

This is not because D is a subclass of C. (Which in your example, btw, it is not.) This is because extension methods are "syntactic sugar" that makes it appear that a method belongs to a class, even when it doesn't. This compiler feature turns any call of `callingObject.Foo();` into `Foo(callingObject);` by the compiler.

In your commented out code, the compiler doesn't know what to use as the first parameter to your extension method (i.e. it doesn't know what you want `this C o` to be) because no object of type `C` or a subclass of `C` is calling it.

If you were to call the extension method from your base class, you would see the same behaviour.

Comment: After i fixed my code to be what i mean - i have a feeling you are right about the answer - but i can argue that the compiler SHOULD know that i want to use this - since this is indeed an instance of C

Comment: @Lee I'd like the compiler to make me breakfast in the morning, hehe. But, seriously, I agree this is something that the compiler could probably be changed to recognize. IMO, you shouldn't be creating extension methods if you have access to change the original code.

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to change the code of the class... Why would you want to use an extension method? Extension methods are useful for those classes you don't have the ability to change. I would imaging this would be a frowned upon programming practice.

Comment: as i wrote in the original question - i gave the example here with full source - but in the real scenario i do NOT have access to the code of C

Comment: If you don't have acress to the code why are you worries about the way it compiles?